# Sending continues data stream in bluetooth Ble with less delay

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

#### Background

I'm developing an android application which can communicates with ***Nordic*** Bluetooth 4 device,
i can able to send and receive data from nordic.

The problem is whenever i want to send bulk data i have to break data in to several 20 byte data and send with delay of 50ms

as i show below code

```
private boolean sendBytes(byte[] iBytes){
    sendResetBytes();
    byte[] arr=new byte[20];
    for(int i=0;i<iBytes.length;i++){
        if(i!=0&&i%20==0){
            if(!mBluetoothGeneric.send(arr))return false;
            arr=new byte[20];
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        arr[i%20]=iBytes[i];
    }
    if(arr.length!=0)
        if(!mBluetoothGeneric.send(arr))return false;
    return true;
}
```

For sending bytes i used uartService library given by Nordic

send() i implemented simply call writeRxCharacteristics() fn

```
 public boolean writeRXCharacteristic(byte[] value)
{


    BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
    showMessage("mBluetoothGatt null"+ mBluetoothGatt);
    if (RxService == null) {
        showMessage("Rx service not found!");
        broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic RxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID);
    if (RxChar == null) {
        showMessage("Rx charateristic not found!");
        broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
        return false;
    }
    RxChar.setValue(value);
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(RxChar);
    return status;
}
```

#### My Question, Is there any method so i can send bulk data to nordic with minimum possible delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First call `setWriteType(WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE)` on the characteristic to be able to send multiple packets in one connection event.

Then you need to write each chunk at a time and wait for onCharacteristicWrite before you send the next one, since there can only be one outstanding GATT operation at a time in Android's BLE stack.

Comment: hi 
i referred your answer and onCharacteristicWrite is calling after wrietCharacter() but how can i suspend execution till the callback is called
with out making it sleep
can you post some code snippet

Comment: Well you can't suspend execution and sleep until the callback comes. You have to send the next chunk in the callback. Use some state variable to know how far you have sent and what data comes next.